# Weird Message in Android Emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I keep getting this weird error message every time I'm testing my app on the Android emulator. It pops up every few seconds non-stop and constantly interrupts me. It's really annoying and I have no clue how to get rid of it, or what it even says. I guess it's in German but I tried translating it using Google, and made no sense of the body, only the title which barely made any sense.

Does someone know how to fix this problem?

Link to image: http://oi54.tinypic.com/v4bcqv.jpg
I'm a new user so I can't post images

**EDIT: I tried uninstalling all the applications I created from the emulator. The message is still there. Below is my manifest file (which someone said might be the cause of the problem): **

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:enabled="true">
    <activity android:name=".QuizSplashActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="QuizGameActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="QuizHelpActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="QuizMenuActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="QuizScoresActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="QuizSettingsActivity"></activity>

</application>
```

**PROBLEM FIXED: apparently all I had to do was replace the AVD with a new one**

Comment: I take it checking emulators region/language settings doesn't show that it's set for German?  I only ask, because for some reason, my original emulator was setup for Japanese or something somehow...

Comment: what apps installed on your emulator? can you test it using new AVD?

Comment: It's not in German. I think it's in Dutch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey,
this is dutch and not german language. i also typed it in the google translator and thats what came out:

"Care, because the application component is enabled. malicious applications can use this to key phone functions off. an authorization must be carefully considered, since application components unusable, inconsistent, or could become unstable."

guess that can be caused by a missing entrance in the manifest file or something like that.
hope the better translation can help you a bit.

Comment: Nice thanks, that helped a lot. What do you think I could be missing in my manifest file?

Comment: @Ryan: I came up with a similar translation using Dutch in Google Translate. As typie34 suggests, it could be a missing manifest permission which is causing it. Also, as forsvarir sugeests, it looks like the language settings for your emulator are set incorrectly.

Comment: I just posted my manifest file for the application. Can you take a look at it? Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan: If you're seeing a popup like that with a 'Force Close' button, there will normally be an exception dump in the logcat. Without knowing what your code is trying to do (access the internet, access phone state, write to SD card etc etc) it's impossible to tell if this is a permissions issue or not. It just seems most likely that it's the case. Getting the emulator to show English error messages might also help solve this.

Comment: in case you didn´t use logcat until now, go to eclipse -> window -> Show View -> Other -> Android -> LogCat;  start your application within the emulator and paste the LogCat entries like MisterSquonk said.

Answer (score 0):

That is extremely weird, I've never seen anything like that before.  Few questions to try and help you troubleshoot:

Does this happen with only one of your applications?

Are you using any third-party libraries?

When you try to run the application from a different computer, do you have this problem?

Is this only on the emulator or when you try to run it on your phone too?

Comment: As far as I know, it happens with all of them. Not sure about third-party libraries. I haven't tried running the emulator on another computer, and I don't plan on it. And I'm planning to run it on my phone once I finish a good part of it (which won't be until a few hours later).